# Evaluating limits of of $f(x)= \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+x}}$

Tags: limits

First I want to evaluate the limit for $x\rightarrow \infty^+$ and $x\rightarrow \infty^-$. I'm already having trouble here. If I were to rewrite the function:

$$f(x)= \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+x}}= \frac{x\,\sqrt{x^2+x}}{x^2+x}=\frac{x^2}{x^2}\frac{\sqrt{1+1/x}}{1+1/x}$$ it becomes clear the function goes closer to $1$ for $\lim_{x\to \infty^+}$. But the same result seems to be true for $\lim_{x\to \infty^-}$ even though the result should be $-1$.

I'm also struggling with finding the limits of $\lim_{x\to -1}$ and $\lim_{x\to 0}$. When $x$ goes close to $-1$ it seems pretty intuitive the function goes down to negative infinity. I don't have a formal explanation for that. If it goes close to $0$ it's a little harder for me why $0$ also is the answer. L'Hopital doesn't do much: $$\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)= \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+x}}\stackrel{"\frac{0}{0}"}{=}\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1\,\sqrt{x^2+x}}{\frac{1}{2}\,(2\,x+1)}$$ So how to get out of this?

Comment: When you factor out $x^2$ from the square root, the result is  $|x|$  rather than $x$. because $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to believe that $\sqrt{x^2+x}=x\sqrt{1+1/x}$, but this is true only when $x>0$; when $x<0$, then $\sqrt{x^2+x}=-x\sqrt{1+1/x}$. That's why you did not get the right answer.

On the other hand, if $x>0$, then$$\frac x{\sqrt{x^2+x}}=\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{x^2+x}}=\sqrt{\frac x{x+1}},$$and therefore$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac x{\sqrt{x^2+x}}=0.$$So, since $f$ is undefined on $[-1,0]$, $\lim_{x\to0}\frac x{\sqrt{x^2+x}}=0$.

Finally, when $x$ approaches $-1$ from the left, $\sqrt{x^2+x}$ approaches $0$, and therefore $\lim_{x\to-1}\frac x{\sqrt{x^2+x}}=-\infty$.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**

You are forgetting the sign of $x$:

\begin{align*}
f(x) = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^{2}+x}} = \frac{x}{|x|\sqrt{1 + \dfrac{1}{x}}} = \frac{\text{sign}(x)}{\sqrt{1 + \dfrac{1}{x}}}
\end{align*}